# How is heat distributed between brake pads and brake discs?

Tags: thermodynamics, friction

In this [analysis](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/162888.pdf) of disc braking it is said

> A part of the heat generated during braking is immediately dissipated
>   into the surrounding air by means of convection. According to [4] this
>   fraction is only in the order of 1%. The fraction of heat that is
>   absorbed by the brake disc is, according to [7] in the order of 93%.
>   The remaining part of the heat is absorbed by the pad.

Why is the energy dissipated at the contact surface not split equally?

Comment: More heat energy flows into the metal brake disk than into non-metallic brake pads because the metal brake disk has higher thermal conductivity.

Comment: I wonder what 'immediately' means here. During the time that the brakes are applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heat is produced by friction between the pad and the disk during brake application. The generated heat is split between the pad and the disk. The most commonly material for the disk is cast iron, which has high heat capacity and large thermal conductivity. Thus disk absorbs the major heat without significant temperature increase. This protects the brake system from over heating and therefore thermal deformation. Because of the disk has larger mass than the pad, it takes more than 90% of heat. The disk temperature will still increase. The temperature difference between the disk and air dissipates the heat from the disk to the air. It will eventually dissipate all of the heat from the disk to air. But during the brake application duration, comparably, air is an insulator and takes little heat from the system during that short period.

Comment: To complete the answer, if I understand correctly, we can keep in mind that heat is generated at the interface in an amount proportional to braking power. That interface between the two materials, being in direct contact, can be more or less assumed to cause the two materials to be at the same temperature. As result, as in the answer, the generated heat gets distributed according to heat capacity.